# How to override main abstract methods from mixins

Tags: flutter, dart

As you see in example,

- I have Core class for distribute the shared variables/methods etc. into the mixins.
- Abstract class for defining necessary methods, providing summary about api.
- Main class for importing everything like a provider.

There isn't any runtime error of course.

Problem with this approach, mixin methods does not recognize `@override` annotation.

I want to create granular, clean structure for my packages. What is the best approach for this situation or what is the mistake I'm doing?

```
abstract class AbstractCore {
  void foo();

  void bar();
}

class Core {
  var shared;
}

mixin Feature1 on Core {
  @override // not recognized by syntax of course
  void foo() {
    // something with [shared]
  }
}

mixin Feature2 on Core {
  @override // not recognized
  void bar() {
    // yet another thing with [shared]
  }
}

class Main with Core, Feature1, Feature2 implements AbstractCore {}
```

You can accept like:

- Core: ApiBase(For sharing Client object, constants, keeping dispose method...)
- Feature1: let's say Authentication related Api calls
- Feature2: let's say Content related Api calls
- Main: Api provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotations don't have any impact on what the code do. They are just used for readability and tooling.

In your care, it is the analyzer that is complaining about `@override`, because you're not overriding anything.

Simply remove the `@override` decorator — it wasn't needed to begin with.

Comment: Thanks for answer Remi, my purpose is readability already. Because it's very useful in big projects. I'll try different structures without mixins but mixin is what I should use as concept I think.

Comment: Yeah but using `@override` here is wrong. You're not overriding anything, you're implementing it.